# TinyMCE getContent Returns Null

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce-6

I'm trying to  get the raw HTML out of TinyMCE editor. Here is the code I am using

```
      tinymce.init({
          selector: 'textarea',
          plugins: 'a11ychecker advcode casechange export formatpainter image editimage linkchecker autolink lists checklist media mediaembed pageembed permanentpen powerpaste table advtable tableofcontents tinycomments tinymcespellchecker',
          toolbar: 'a11ycheck addcomment showcomments casechange checklist code export formatpainter image editimage pageembed permanentpen table tableofcontents',
          toolbar_mode: 'floating',
          tinycomments_mode: 'embedded',
          tinycomments_author: 'Author name',

         
        });

        console.log (tinymce.get('content-text'))
```

In the console it says null. I have also used the active editor function.

```
console.log (tinymce.activeEditor.getContent())
```

Doing this gives me an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContent')
    at contact-us.html:62:43
```

I'm using TinyMCE version 6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the `<script>` to below the `<textarea>` and try again.

Or try to add ID onto `textarea` tag like

```html
<textarea id="tinyarea">
...
</textarea>
```

and change selector in the js to

```js
selector: 'textarea#tinyarea',
```

Comment: I tried doing that and I still get the same error ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContent')
    at contact-us.html:62:43````

Comment: Show fragment at 62 line of the contact-us.html? And maybe you got any errors inside console? You tried to write `tinymce` inside console? Is it defined object?

Comment: This is what the line of code looks like console.log (tinymce.get("contact-text").getContent())  The fragment is .getContent())

Comment: @Ethan `contact-text` element after script or before? Also try to check what contact-text element is. Is it class name or id? And change `"contact-text"` to `".contact-text"` or `"#contact-text"`

Comment: The script tag is after the element. I also have tried selcting the element with .contact-text  and #contact-text

Comment: @Ethan open console in the browser and show me a log. Press F12, F5 before. And how much textarea tags on the page?

Comment: Problem migth be in referrer policy